# Find a line in a file based on user input

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.x

Currently this program finds all the lines with the specific words you ask it to find, but how can I change this so that it stores all the multiple line numbers as different values which I can then manipulate later. Or how to find the specific occurrence of the phrase.

```
a = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
lookup = a
with open('FileName') as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            print 'found at line:', num
```

Comment: How could I get a specific occurrences line number? Because currently it prints out all the line numbers for the specific phrase but I just want to get the third occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the `num`, you can just store it to a list (or do both).

```
found = []
for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
    if lookup in line:
        print 'found at line:', num
        found.append(num)
        # found.append((line,num)) # use this if you want to store both the line and the number
```

The short version of this would be:

```
found = [num for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1) if lookup in line]
```

Short version with printing of `num`:

```
found = [num for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1) if lookup in line and not print(num)]
```

This will give you a list `found` which stores all the `nums` for which your lookup succeeded.

Comment: or less readably: `found = [(num, line) for (num, line) in enumerate(myFile, 1) if lookup in line]`

Comment: What would I do to save each individual line number as a separate variable?

Comment: @Nick you can access the values by indexing into `found`, e.g. `found[0]` is the `num` of the first line where your lookup succeeded, `found[1]` is the `num` of second line, and so on. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason I am getting an error when I add the:found = [(num, line) for (num, line) in enumerate(myFile, 1) if lookup in line] into my code

Comment: @Nick then don't put that there. Use the answer's code, not mine specifically noted as "less readable"

Comment: @timgeb ewww @ your last snippet. I hate using side effects in a list comp

Comment: @AdamSmith I like it occasionally. For example when killing duplicates from a list while keeping the order. [x for x in lst if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)] where `seen` is an initally empty set.

Comment: @timgeb certainly considerably faster than my solution, which would be something more like `[item for i,item in set(sorted([(i, item) for i, item in enumerate(lst)], key=lambda x: x[0]))]`

Comment: @timgeb or even something hacky like building a custom set that saves insertion order. Where's `collections.OrderedSet` when I need it! :).

Comment: Since you guys are so smart, I'm kind of stuck, so I'm using the program above to essentially find the line numbers of where specific blocks of data start and end in a big file, so I need to be able to to store each line number as a different variable and then input those variables into another program which prints them into a command line in linux which uses the numbers to use the head and tail commands to cut the data blocks out. But I'm stuck on how to get the line numbers into variables and how to pair the line numbers together. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
lookup = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
with open("FileName") as myfile:
    found = {num: line for (num, line) in enumerate(myfile, 1)}
```

This is how I'd do it. The dict comp is a little terse, but spelled out it does:

```
found = {} # empty dict
for num, line in enumerate(myfile, 1):
    found[num] = line
```

This will let you play with the dictionary like so:

```
for lineno, line in found.items():
    print "{:03}: {}".format(lineno, line)
```

EDIT FOR YOUR QUESTION IN THE COMMENTS

I'd use regex for that personally, rather than trying to bash it together. However to answer your question:

```
startsentry="DATA STARTS ON THE NEXT LINE"
endsentry="DATA ENDS ON THE PREVIOUS LINE"

with open('path/to/file') as myfile:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(myfile, 1):
        if startsentry in line:
            _start = line_num+1
        if endsentry in line:
            _end = line_num
    data_is_in = (_start, _end)
```

Comment: Is there a way to find a line using a keyword and then print all the stuff under that line until I hit another keyword?

Comment: I found a very simple way to do it:for i,line in enumerate(open("FILE")):
    if i >= 95 and i < 97 :
        print line,
for i,line in enumerate(open("FILE")):
    if i >= 133 and i < 134 :
        print line,
for i,line in enumerate(open("FILE")):
   if i >= 196 and i < 2197 :
      print line,
for i,line in enumerate(open("FILE")):
    if i >= 2225 and i < 4227 :
        print line,
now all I have to do is be able to get the line numbers into variables which I am super stuck on :(

Comment: @Nick may be worth posting your own answer then. Comments are awful for formatting.

Comment: Apparently since I am new to this website I cant answer my own question for 8 hours...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a different approach, something like:

```
lines = []
with open("file") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

phrases = filter( lambda x: "foo" in x[1], enumerate(lines) )
print phrases
```

Now you are left with an array of line numbers and phrase pairs matching "foo".

**update**: Change to enumerate per comment (thanks!).

Comment: remember your `enumerate` builtin! `lines = enumerate(f)` is the same as your `lines = f.readlines(); lines = zip( ... )` except far less memory-intensive :)